# Is it possible to determine which links on the site have been clicked by the user and which have not yet been placed by the user?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, visited

There is a list of links, I need to track which of them have already been clicked, and which have not been clicked yet.

For example:
There are no links that have been clicked, I should start with the first one.
The first and second links have been placed, you should start with the third.

How can this be implemented?

Was looking to find a solution using querySelector and a:visited, but the browser won't let me access that information.

[replit](https://replit.com/@VovikOvcharuk/links-lol)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+visited+links+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Use localStorage and event listener

Comment: @mplungjan There's no "it" in that sentence, it says "I". I think it's referring to what the user is expected to do.

Comment: I should start/You should start. Some kind of game? Very unclear in any case

Comment: Use localStorage and event listener - @mplungjan

Can you please tell me how to do this? Share a source with an example of how to implement your idea.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stackoverflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] HERE instead of a link that can be changed or go stale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a localStorage version.

On your server, remove `['https://www.youtube.com/']; //` including the comment slashes

Also remove the `e.preventDefault()` I put to check the link gets highlighted

```js
// on your server remove the test "['https://www.youtube.com/']; //" below - localStorage is not supported in snippets
const visitedList = ['https://www.youtube.com/']; // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visited') || '[]');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.cont');
  const links = container.querySelectorAll('.link');
  const setVisit = (href) => {
    if (href && !visitedList.includes(href)) visitedList.push(href);
    links.forEach(link => {
      if (visitedList.includes(link.href)) link.classList.add('visited');
    });
  };
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); // comment this out after testing
    const tgt = e.target.closest('a.link');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a link
    setVisit(tgt.href);
  });
  setVisit();
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 20px;
}

.link {
  color: #a955ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link.visited {
  /* changed from .link:visited to manage ourselves */
  color: #ff5b55;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="https://github.com/">Github</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="https://www.netflix.com/">Netflix</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="https://dribbble.com/">Dribbble</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```